# Linux pts , trying to get return value from one script to another in a different pts's

Tags: linux, bash, embedded-linux

lets say I want to send the return sum value, should be 55, from this script "for_loop.sh" via pts to another script in different pts.
GNU nano 2.9.3                       for_loop

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start counting"
sum=0
function Sum()
{
for i in {1..10} 
do
        sum=$((sum+$i))
        echo $i
        sleep 3s
done
echo "The sum of the organs the organs is: $sum"
}

Sum
```

by typing this in command line: ./for_loop > /dev/pts/2

in the other pts I want to check in another script that i get the correct value of the sum(55).
if does will print "You got the correct value" else will print "You got wrong value"

I have tried this bash script called "checkNum"

```
#!/bin/bash


function myFunc ()
{

echo "The number you got is $1"

if [ $1 -eq 55 ]
then
        echo "You got the right number from the second terminal"
else
        echo "You got wrong number from the second terminal, something is wrong."
fi

}


flag=1
while [ $flag -eq 1 ]
do
        echo "Wait.."
        sleep 5s
        if [ /dev/pts/2 ]
        then
                num=$1
                echo "The number is: $num"
                flag=0
##summon the function above##

                myFunc num
        fi
done
```

in the command line i wrote "./checkNUm < /dev/pts/2"
how should I do it right?

Comment: `myFunc num` → `myFunc $num`

Comment: What is `[ /dev/pts/2 ]` supposed to test? And `num=$1` will keep assigning the same value to `$num` on every iteration.

Comment: Why in the world are you using `pts`s here at all? What's that meant to accomplish, particularly in an embedded (and thus presumably headless) system?

Comment: If you want to coordinate between two scripts, where one reads that the other writes, use named FIFOs or UNIX sockets or -- heck -- TCP for that. A pts is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: pty does not work as you expected. data written to a pty will not become another process's input (stdin). no magic like this (unless you use both ptm and pts).

Comment: Well I'm new and I see some bad mistakes that I have done.I'm finally make this thing works properly and send messages throw scripts between 2 different terminals.
I delete the if statement inside the while loop, and change myFunc ret -> myFunc $ret
And also i use read ret < /dev/pts/2, and after that send the ret parameter to the function